# Delete from main table records that apear in cte

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a main table from which I need to delete rows that are returned in CTE
Preferably I would like to do something  like that:

```
with users_to_exclude as (
select uid, date, location_id
from some_previous_ctes_with_logic
)
delete from main_table mt
inner join 
users_to_exclude ux
 on ux.uid = mt.uid
 and ux.date = mt.date
 and ux.location_id = mt.location_id
```

But I have not idea how to approach this in GBQ.
If I had only one key by which I would delete, it would be simpler as I would use all the CTE with a final `select field` in the `where` clause.
But `where (f1,f2,f3) in (select f1,f2,f3 from..)` is not possible in GBQ to my understanding.

So not sure how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
delete from main_table mt
where exists (
  with users_to_exclude as (
    select uid, date, location_id
    from some_previous_ctes_with_logic
  )
  select 1 from users_to_exclude ux
  where ux.uid = mt.uid
  and ux.date = mt.date
  and ux.location_id = mt.location_id
);
```

> why do I have to attach it to the main table in the where clause?
> If for some reason you want to go this direction - use below

```
delete from main_table mt
where (uid, date, location_id) in (
  with users_to_exclude as (
    select uid, date, location_id
    from some_previous_ctes_with_logic
  )
  select as struct  * from users_to_exclude
);
```

Comment: seems like it's getting the job done. Yet could you please explain the logic? :  select 1 and not * here is out of convenience? if `where exists` contains the relevant rows, why do I have to attach it to the main table in the `where` clause? I'm asking because I'm assuming that it works similar to `where id in (select id from table)`, but I guess it isn't, so what is the difference?

Comment: `select 1` and `select *` in this case are the same as the purpose is just to identify if record exists or not. `Why select 1`? - because as a rule I usually avoid to use `*`

Comment: as of use `where id in` - see update in the answer